# subscript in DOT/graphviz edge labels

Tags: graphviz, dot

How do you use Graphviz/DOT's HTML features to add a subscript character to an edge label?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like this:

```
digraph g {
  1 -> 2 [label=<Regular<SUB>subscript</SUB>>];
}
```

Comment: What if I got char like "<" or ">" in the label? Who to escape them?

Comment: @enchanter According to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), one can [encode](http://www.html-entities.org/) many special characters. "<" becomes `&lt;` and ">" is `&gt;`. UTF-8 HTML encodings `&#x003c;` and `&#x003e;` do also work with Graphviz labels.