# subscripts & greek letters in dot edge labels

Tags: r, math, fonts, graphviz, dot

This is a followup to [Using symbol font / math notation in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040997/using-symbol-font-math-notation-in-graphviz), and was also posted on the Graphviz discussion forum, http://www.graphviz.org/content/subscripts-greek-letters-dot-edge-labels, but there has been no response.

[Env: graphviz 2.38, Windows 7]

I'm working on a project to create path diagrams for structural equation models in R with the [sem](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=245) package
The sem package contains a function, pathDiagram, that does this reasonably well, by constructing the required code for dot.

We use two back-end renderers: dot itself, with -Tpdf, and the R [DiagrammeR package](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR), that uses javascript libraries grViz and mermaid.

We recently added code to allow rendering edge labels using greek letters and subscripts, by
using the UTF-8 character equivalents, eg

```
"beta" "&#946;" "&#x3B2;"
"gamma" "&#947;" "&#x3B3;"
```

and

```
subscripts <- c("₀", "₁", "₂", "₃", "₄", "₅", "₆",
"₇", "₈", "₉")
```

We find that this works perfectly with DiagrammeR. With dot, we *do* get the Greek letters, but
nothing we have tried allows us to get subscripts from the standard command
dot -T pdf -o file.pdf file.dot
All we get are those little boxes with the 4-digit character code.

Is this a bug or limitation of dot? Is there any work-around?

Here is an example of a dot file generated by our software that illustrates this behavior.

```
digraph "union.sem" {
  rankdir=LR;
  size="8,8";
  node [fontname="Helvetica" fontsize=14 fillcolor="transparent" shape=box style=filled];
  edge [fontname="Helvetica" fontsize=10];
  center=1;
  {rank=min "x1"}
   {rank=min "x2"}
  "y1" [fillcolor="transparent"]
  "y2" [fillcolor="transparent"]
  "y3" [fillcolor="transparent"]
  "x2" -> "y1" [label="&#947;&#770;&2081;&2082;=-0.09" color=red penwidth=1.001];
  "y1" -> "y2" [label="&#946;&#8322;&#8321;=-0.28" color=red penwidth=1.001];
  "x2" -> "y2" [label="&#947;&#8322;&#8322;=0.06" color=black penwidth=1.001];
  "y1" -> "y3" [label="&#946;&#8323;&#8321;=-0.22" color=red penwidth=1.001];
  "y2" -> "y3" [label="&#946;&#8323;&#8321;=0.85" color=black penwidth=1.001];
  "x1" -> "y3" [label="&#947;&#8323;&#8321;=0.86" color=black penwidth=1.001];
  "x1" -> "x2" [label="&#963;&#8321;&#8322;=7.14" dir=both color=black penwidth=1.001];
  // variable labels: 
    "y1" [label="Deference"];
    "y2" [label="Activism"];
    "y3" [label="Sentiment"];
    "x1" [label="Years"];
    "x2" [label="Age"];
}
```

And the result (using -Tpng)

[image]

(In this example, I also tried using Unicode characters for the subscripts in the `x2 -> y1` path, these taken from [How to find the unicode of the subscript alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908593/how-to-find-the-unicode-of-the-subscript-alphabet), but these just appear as their `&2081;` strings.)

Comment: The subscripts render using dot on ubuntu 14.04 (except the edge x2 -> y1) : perhaps a windows issue rather than dot

Comment: Thanks -- that's helpful in tracking it down. The question is *what kind* of Windows issue.  I thought it might be related to using `fontname="Helvetica"` for the edges, but removing that gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using [Html-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and the [SUB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12387732/63733) tag instead of html escape characters.

Example:

```
1 -> 2 [label=<&#947;<SUB>0</SUB>>];
```